# Webservice with JAXB and without JAXB

Tags: web-services, jaxb

I created a webservice in eclipse using bottom-up approach and it worked fine. I didn't have to use JAXB in that. So in what scenarios I have to use JAXB in web services?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One scenario is when you want to generate your web services using JAX-WS, [which relies on JAXB](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E13222_01/wls/docs103/webserv/data_types.html)

See [this example here](http://tomee.apache.org/examples-trunk/simple-webservice/README.html).

Answer (score 0):

If you need to do things already implemented by JAXB, then it is usually a very bad idea to reinvent the wheel: you won't benefit of that project experience, you will forget some use cases, security issues... or even badly implement the specification.
Unless you think that you could do better or different than what is already done by JAXB, then use JAXB.
Given the assumption that you fit the licensing terms of course: CDDL v1.1 and GPL v2.